# Possible to use older vc6 .lib built in VS2003 in a VS2010 or newer project? Getting LNK2001 errors on one repeated function call (type_info::name)

Tags: visual-c++, static-libraries, linker-errors, lnk2001

I'm working on an older c++ Visual Studio 2003 project which uses a static .lib (of which the source code is lost to time) that I would like to move to Visual studio 2010 or newer.  There are a bunch of LNK2001 linker errors, all to the same symbol, when trying to build in 2010:

> LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) >public: char const * >__thiscall type_info::name(void)const " (__imp_?>name@type_info@@QBEPBDXZ)

After doing some digging, it appears that trying to build with an older static library in a newer version of MS c++ is troublesome or possibly impossible and  this particular error occurs because the newer MSVCRT.dll used by VS2005+ has a different definition for type_info::name(void):

> type_info::name(__type_info_node*)

There is an MSDN forum issue [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f787a1eb-e1bd-4866-a08a-beb02c2915fd/vs2005-linker-error-with-typeid?forum=vcgeneral) with the same problem, which it appears the original poster may have gotten a solution to - he at least got it to build, which I was not able to do using the workaround given of putting the following code into the project:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma warning(disable:4273)
struct __type_info_node {
    void *memPtr;
    __type_info_node* next;
};
extern __type_info_node __type_info_root_node;

class type_info {
public:
  __declspec(dllimport) const char* name() const;
  __declspec(dllimport) const char* name(__type_info_node*) const;
};
const char* type_info::name() const {
  return name(&__type_info_root_node);
}
```

I tried building in different ways with that code - inserted into an existing file, a new file, and compiling it into a .obj and using the lib.exe tool to update the original .lib with said .obj and then building, but all attempts ended up with the original errors or different ones - redefinition errors for type_info::name.  I'm fairly new to c/c++ & VS so maybe I'm missing something.

Does anyone know of a way to workaround this and build in a newer version of VS?   Or am I stuck using the 2003 version?

Comment: Personally I'd bite the bullet and upgrade and just fix the code so it works with VS2013.

Comment: Unfortunately the source code for this older library is lost so I can't access the source to change it, I just have the .lib file and the headers files.

Comment: Then you're SOL, I would see if there is an open source replacement. Microsoft deliberately breaks the C++ ABI between versions to prevent binary compat issues